# Updating Map Marker position from onPostExecute(), App crashing while rotating device

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My map app is continuously fetching the location data from server using AsynTtask repeatedly using handler(every 10th second). To update the marker position i am using onPostExecute(). But the app is crashing on rotating the device. As far i know it is because the MainActivity reference is no more there,So what is the solution/best practice for it ??
(i am implementing interface to run onPostExecute() from main activity)
Here is the half code, let me know if more log/codes is required. Thanks

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                                            OnMapReadyCallback, 
                                            TrackLocationTask.AsyncMarkerUpdate {
protected Marker mMarker;
protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
protected MapFragment mapFragment;
private Handler mHandler;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startTrackDevice(); 
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String appServerUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.hostname)
                +"/track.php?uuid="
                +android_id;
        TrackLocationTask track = new TrackLocationTask();
        track.delegate= MainActivity.this;
        track.execute(appServerUrl);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 10000);
    }
};

private void startTrackDevice() {
    mStatusChecker.run();
}
public void updateMarker(String result) {
    String[] results = result.split(";");
    float lat = Float.parseFloat(results[0]);
    float lng = Float.parseFloat(results[1]);
    mMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat,lng));
    mapFragment.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(lat, lng), 18));
}
```

**TrackLocationTask.java**

```
public class TrackLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
public interface AsyncMarkerUpdate {
    public void updateMarker(String result);
}
public AsyncMarkerUpdate delegate=null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String locationString = "response";
    try {
            // bla bla code to handle response and setting result
        } else{
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return locationString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(delegate!=null)
        delegate.updateMarker(result);
}
```

**log**

```
09-22 14:03:38.543    8319-8319/in.mydomain.tracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at in.mydomain.tracker.MainActivity.updateMarker(MainActivity.java:292)
        at in.mydomain.tracker.TrackLocationTask.onPostExecute(TrackLocationTask.java:53)
        at in.mydomain.tracker.TrackLocationTask.onPostExecute(TrackLocationTask.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably crashing because you are trying to update the UI in a background thread. Try:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

Other option is:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

Comment: i am updating ui on onPostExecute() and it working perfectly until device orientation is not changed

Comment: No, it's still crashing

Answer (score 0):

App crashes becouse after rotation you have two instances of your MainActivity. In class  **TrackLocationTask** you have hard reference to MainActivity. So two **TrackLocationTask** tasks are started. First task whant to run method  *updateMarker* from first MainActivity. This activity was destroyed , so it crashes. 
What you should do:

You can set null to your reference to *delegate* in **TrackLocationTask** in *onPostExecute* , and canceling task for onDestroy() .

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
                                        OnMapReadyCallback, 
                                        TrackLocationTask.AsyncMarkerUpdate {  

...
private TrackLocationTask track;
private Runnable mStatusChecker;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onDestroy(){
      super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    mStatusChecker =null;
    if(track!=null){
       track.delegate=null;
       track.cancel(true);
       track=null;
     } 
    mHandler=null;
   }
 }
```

This above is adaptation for your code. Better practice is to extends application class. You can executing long operations in application context. Results to fragments / activities you can send using EventBus.

Comment: can you please give any reference link ?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) this is for Sending messages. [link](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/) extending application class.